# How to setup the Hololens2 with the MixedReality

Tags: windows-mixed-reality

I plugin my hololens2 into my PC. and open the OpenXR Developer Tools for Windows Mixed Reality SW, but it show does not have a head mounted display.
I run the hello_xr project, when invokes the XrGetSystem function, it return XR_ERROR_FORM_FACTOR_UNAVAILABLE, I think it is cannot find the helolens2 device.
How can I do to find the HMD device.

Answer (score 0):

> I plugin my hololens2 into my PC. and open the OpenXR Developer Tools for Windows Mixed Reality SW, but it show does not have a head mounted display.

The OpenXR Developer Tools for Windows Mixed Reality on PC is only worked for the WMR headsets instead of HoloLens. For HoloLens2, the OpenXR Developer Tools should be installed through the Windows Device Portal or Microsoft Store on HoloLens, and there is a demo scene to test OpenXR runtime.

For Device Portal way, please navigate to the "OpenXR" page and then click the "Install" button under "Developer Features".

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
You mean the OpenXR Developer tools should install on Hololens not PC, right?

Comment: Yes, it should be installed on the HoloLens.